# Parsing multiple XMLs with few tags missing using pyspark

Tags: xml, pyspark

I am parsing multiple XMLs where all the tags may not be present at all times in all the XMLs. Eg.

Sample1:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<employees>
<employee department="ENG">
<name id="1"/>
<joinyear value="2010"/>
<salary value="6000"/>
</employee>
</employees>
```

Sample 2:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<employees>
<employee department="ELE">
<name id="2"/>
<joinyear value="2020"/>
<salary/>
</employee>
</employees>
```

When I'm trying to parse both the XMLs together, i get all the elements as struct with _value and _VALUE except in the second XML where I get salary as a string instead of a struct and it fails, how do I fix this if certain tags have no values sometimes in them?
I am using spark-xml package.

Comment: Similar to following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73988322/parse-a-large-xml-by-certain-count-of-records-by-records-using-the-sax-parser-in/73989927#73989927  I can easily solve with a powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

If all source files don't have the same schema, try using this.

```py
df = spark.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
      .option("rowTag", "employees")
      .xml("path/*.xml")
```

Comment: Says dataframe has no object 'xml'. Could that be related to the version of spark-xml I'm using? It's 2.13.0 0.15